# Spring Boot HTTP made secure (HTTPS) with Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new at Kubernetes and GKE. I have some microservices written in Spring Boot 2 and deployed from GitHub to GKE. I would like to make these services secure and I want to know if it's possible to use ingress on my gateway microservice to make the entry point secure just like that. I created an ingress with HTTPS but it seems all my health checks are failing.

Is it possible to make my architecture secure just by using ingress and not change the spring boot apps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It would be possible to use a GKE ingress given your scenario, there is an official [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) on how to do this step by step.

Additionally, here's a step by step [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) on how to implement Google Managed certs.

Also, I understand that my response is somewhat general, but I can only help you so much without knowing your GKE infrastructure (like your DNS name for said certificate among other things).

Remember that you must implement this directly on your GKE infrastructure and not on your GCP side, if you modify or create something new outside GKE but that it's linked to GKE, you might see that either your deployment rolled back after a certain time or that stopped working after a certain time.

Edit:

I will assume several things here, and since I don't have your Spring Boot 2 deployment yaml file, I will replace that with an nginx deployment.

cert.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: ssl-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - example.com
```

nginx.yaml

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "nginx"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "nginx"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "nginx"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "nginx"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "nginx-1"
        image: "nginx:latest"
```

nodeport.yaml (please modify "targetPort: 80" to your needs)

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Service"
metadata:
  name: "nginx-service"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "nginx"
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: "nginx"
  type: "NodePort"
```

ingress-cert.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: ssl-cert
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: nginx-service
    servicePort: 80
```

Keep in mind that assuming your DNS name "example.com" is pointing into your Load Balancer external IP, it could take a while to your SSL certificate to be created and applied.

Comment: Thank you for your response. DNS name is something I came up at that moment, something that came appropiate, I don't own that DNS. I created a new Google managed certificate when creating the Ingress but all my backend are in unhealthy state. I thought this is enough to have HTTPS ingress with http backend services. What are my next steps?

Comment: Edited anwer to ilustrate some yaml files, as for why your backends are on unhealthy state, I am not sure since I don't have visibility into your GCP project, but taking a wild guess here, I suppose your "targetPort: 80" is using an incorrect port (this depends on your Spring deployment) and / or your Spring deploying is answering with something different from HTTP [200](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#criteria-protocol-http) OK code.

Comment: Thanks @Frank for sharing this. So what I have is a Spring Boot app (a Spring Cloud Zuul Gateway actually) that listens on server 8762. The Kubernetes load balancer service actually maps all requests from port 80 to 8762. Tested, everything runs smoothly with http. My goal is to make this service use https. The healthcheck (default one) did actually hit / path which was incorrect so I changed it to /actuator/health (because i have the actuator dependency in the spring boot app). Still my ingress says that all my backend services are unhealthy. what information should I give you?

Comment: What more information can I offer to this question so that everything is transparent?